# To find solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the continous solutionof

$$\frac{dy}{dx} +y = G (x),\qquad x \geq 0,\quad y (0) = 2 $$

where

$$G (x) = \begin{cases} 3 & \text{when }x\in [0, \pi/2) \\
\cos x & \text{when $x\ge \pi/2$}
\end{cases}
$$

ATTEMPT  : I have formed two differential equations and solved both of them  , and i have determined constant for first differential equation using initial condition given but for second differential equation how do i determine integrating constant ? THANKS

Comment: are the two $g, G$ different?

Comment: @abel nothey are not .i edited

Comment: Glue it with the solution of the first differential equation at $x=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we will solve the differential equation in two pieces. on $0 \le x \le \pi/2$
you find $$y = 3 - e^{-x} $$ therefore $y(\pi/2) = 3 - e^{-\pi/2}$

now we solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} + y = \cos x, y(\pi/2) =  3 - e^{-\pi/2} \text{ on } \pi/2 \le x \le \pi.$$

the particular solution is $y_P = \dfrac{1}{2}(\sin x + \cos x)$
and the homogeneous solution is $y_H = Ce^{-x}$ so the general solution is 
$$ y= \dfrac{1}{2}(\sin x + \cos x) + Ce^{-x} $$ now use the condition at $x = \pi/2$ to determine $C$.

Comment: How can you plug pi/2 infirst differential equation , its not in interval

Comment: it is the boundary. you are looking for a continuous function on $[0, \pi]$ and differentiable everywhere except at $x = \pi/2$ at which point $y^\prime$ has a jump discontinuity of $2$ the same jump of $G.$